# retorno JSON com caracteres especiais em URL

Tags: php, json, utf-8, encode

Estou tendo um problema com o retorno de um JSON, fiz uma query para buscar umas imagens do banco, algumas URL os usuários cadastraram as imagens com caracteres especiais como -> **(ç ã)** os textos que contém estes tipos de caracteres estão retornando certos, não há problemas.

Algumas URLs que estão no banco:

```
media/upload/revista/capa_edição_810.jpg
media/upload/revista/capa_edição_806.jpg
```

No retorno do JSON estão vindo assim:

```
media/upload/revista/capa_edi/u00c3/u00a7/u00c3/u00a3o_810.jpg
media/upload/revista/capa_edi/u00c3/u00a7/u00c3/u00a3o_806.jpg
```

Meu código em PHP:

```
<?php

require_once('conexao.php');

$query = " SELECT CONCAT('http://www.meusite.com.br/media/', imagem) as imagem, \n" 
    ." concat('edicao_', rr.edicao) as edicao, rr.edicao as numedicao, ei.id as Id_revista  \n"
    ." FROM `revistas_revista` rr   \n"
    ." inner join edicao_impressa_edicaoanterior ei on ei.revista_anterior_id = rr.id   \n"
    ."  where ei.ativo = 1 and year(rr.data) = '".$_GET['Ano']."' \n"
    ." order by edicao desc ";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Erro ao buscar dados");

mysql_close();  

$linhas = array();   

while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $linhas[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($linhas); 

?>
```

Aguma solução para este problema?

Comment: O problema pode ser em algum tipo de gambiarra como essa aqui: `array_map('utf8_encode', $r);` fazendo duplo encoding nos nomes dos arquivos (no caso, o nome da variável nem bate, deve ser um teste anterior, mas indica Programação Orientada a Chute). Este tipo de problema pode ser detectado com um simples teste de impressão dos dados pra debug do código. Na dúvida, imprima em hexadecimal as strings pra ver exatamente como estão codificadas. Como você postou o código com partes faltando, não dá pra dar muitos detalhes a mais.

Comment: Mesmo assim vale o comentário acima. Você provavelmente está com duplo encoding de utf-8, ou iso sendo interpretado como utf, e para localizar o problema precisa testar desde o DB até o encode pra tenhar achar onde aconteceu. Por exemplo, `/u00c3/u00a7` é o seu Ç, que por algum motivo foi desmembrado em 2 pontos unicode. Isso é muito comum em duplo  encoding.

Comment: entendi, mas o engraçado que na parte que retorna texto está correto, qualquer texto que tenha esse tipo de caracter especial vem correto, somente neste campo URL.

Comment: não se leve pelo que aparece na tela, imprima em hexadecimal e confira os bytes. Precisa ver se o DB está correto tambem. De repente os dados tao em UTF, mas a tabela ou o campo estão configurados de maneira errada, em ISO. O problema pode ter até acontecido antes, na hora de alimentar o DB. Daria até pra fazer um remendão e usar um utf8_decode( $nomedoarquivo), mas aí é abrir a porta do inferno de vez. Seria a técnica Extreme Go Horse levada aos extremos (pra teste serve, pra usar na prática, de jeito nenhum).

Comment: Se vc usa o MySQL Workbech ou o Query Browser, dá pra visualizar em hexa direto no DB também.

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE resolveu para mim, mas é um bug esquisito.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solução rápida.

Basta copiar e colar.

Não precisa usar muito o cérebro.

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $linhas[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($linhas);
```

Troque por isso e tá tudo sussa!

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $linhas[] = utf8_decode($r);
}

echo json_encode($linhas, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

O restante da resposta é para o caso querer entender o que foi feito.

Continue lendo se quiser consertar o problema da forma correta.

## Resposta detalhada.

<sub>nota: Precisa de um pouco de cérebro para continuar lendo. Textos com mais de 3 linhas dão sono. Boa sorte.</sub>

## Referente a questão

Não entendi muito bem o que realmente quer, mas subentendo que deseja exibir no retorno do json, os caracteres na sua forma original.

A função [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) automaticamente codifica caracteres especiais e aplica caracteres de escape. Por isso obtém o resultado como `uxxxx`.

## Solução simples (PHP5.4+)

Uma forma simples para resolver é definir o segundo parâmetro da função [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode). Existe uma constante chamada [JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php), a qual pode ser usada assim:

```
echo json_encode(array('acentuação'), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// retorna 
// ["acentuação"]

echo json_encode(array('acentuação'));
// retorna 
// ["acentua\u00e7\u00e3o"]
```

## Retrocompatibilidade

Para garantir maior compatibilidade, segue abaixo um exemplo de como criar uma retrocompatibilidade com versões do PHP inferiores a 5.4:

O motivo disso é que esse recurso da função `json_encode()` está disponível a partir do PHP5.4. Atualmente ainda é comum encontrar servidores com PHP inferior  a versão 5.4, por isso ainda é válido aplicar essa técnica.

```
function JsonEncode($val, $option = null)
    {

        if (empty($option)) {
            return json_encode($val);
        }

        if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.4) {
            return json_encode($val, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        } else {
            // $option == JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
            $encoded = json_encode($val);
            //$unescaped = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u(\w{4})/', function ($matches) {
            $unescaped = preg_replace_callback(
                '/(?<!\\\\)\\\\u(\w{4})/',
                function ($matches) {
                    return html_entity_decode('&#x' . $matches[1] . ';', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
                },
                $encoded
            );
            return $unescaped;
        }
    }

// Usage sample
echo JsonEncode(array('acentuação'));
// retorna 
// ["acentuação"]
```

## Dupla condificação

Segundo observações do @Bacco, o seu código original está provavelmente aplicando dupla codificação, por isso gera um código errôneo.

O formato unicode da string `ção` é `\u00e7\u00e3o`. No entanto, no código apresentado na pergunta exibe `\u00c3\u00a7\u00c3\u00a3o`

Num simples teste, simulei dupla codificação e bateu 100% com o resultado da pergunta:

```
$str = 'acentuação';
$str_utf8 = utf8_encode($str);
echo PHP_EOL.$str_utf8;
echo PHP_EOL.json_encode($str_utf8);
// retorna
//u00c3/u00a7/u00c3/u00a3o_810

// Esse aqui é o correto como deveria retornar
echo PHP_EOL.json_encode(array($str));
```

Para resolver o seu caso específico, há uma opção fácil e burra que é varrer a sujeira para debaixo do tapete:

```
utf8_decode(json_encode($val, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

A segunda opção é fazer do "jeito certo", eliminando o problema na raíz. Procure onde está aplicando a dupla codificação e corrija. Eliminando assim o uso desnecessário de [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode) e [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/utf8_decode).

<sub>O código completo do teste: https://ideone.com/kHyBVf</sub>

<sub>Nota: O uso de [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/utf8_encode) e [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/utf8_decode) é desnecessário sob o contexto na pergunta. Não quer dizer que seja totalmente desnecessário, mas sim que está sendo mal usado.</sub>

Comment: O problema é que `çã` não deveria ser `/u00c3/u00a7/u00c3/u00a3`. e sim `/u00e7/u00e3`. Algo está desmembrando o `e7` nos seus bytes individuais `c3 a7`. Grande chance de duplo encoding ou UTF sendo tratado como ISO.

Comment: bem observado. Fiz um teste. Eu não tinha testado o unicode da pergunta. Mas num simples teste comprovei que realmente está certo o que você observou. Adicionei na resposta acima.