# Problema com Json_encode

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte codigo?

```
if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $temp[] = $row;
    }
}
$result->close();



foreach ($temp as $x) {
    $x['seat_number'];       //OUTPUT: 4-12-7
    $x['payment_status'];    //OUTPUT: 2-1-2
}
```

Como fazer o array $temp ficar ordenado desta forma: [4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]

```
//Funciona
//echo json_encode([4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]);
```

Porque que este 2 códigos json_encode retornam diferentes valores:

**1º**

```
$teste = '[4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]';
echo json_encode(utf8_encode($teste));
```

**2º**

```
echo json_encode([4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]);
```

Comment: relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141036/4793

Answer (score 1):

Por que no primeiro caso você está fornecendo uma string como parâmetro. E então o PHP entende que você quer codificar uma simples string no formato JSON. E é isso que é exibido. O conteúdo da string é indiferente. Vai ser sempre uma string a ser convertida para o formato JSON.

O segundo caso é um array. E o PHP converte o array fornecido em um array no formato JSON.

Para mais informações: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Porque um é somente uma string enquanto o outro é uma array.

---

Quando faz isso:

```
echo json_encode([4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]);
```

É o mesmo de estar fazendo isso:

```
$array = array(4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Os `[]` apartir do  PHP 5.4 indicam uma array, sendo assim, isto `array(4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2)` e isto `[4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]` são igualmente reconhecidos como array.

---

Quando faz isso:

```
$teste = '[4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]';
echo json_encode(utf8_encode($teste));
```

Você está com uma string normal, *um texto*, é o *mesmo* de fazer isso:

```
echo json_encode('[4 => 2, 12 => 1, 7 => 2]');
```

Uma vez que a informação está entre `'` (ou `"`) está tratado como uma simples string e não mais uma array.

---

*Apenas para complementar, se seu interesse é "preservar a string", você pode acrescentar o `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` ao `json_encode`, exemplo:*

```
$teste = [4 => 'ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ.', 12 => '側経意責家方家閉討店暖育田庁載社転線宇'];
```

```
echo json_encode($teste, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// Resultado: 
// {"4":"ᚠᛇᚻ᛫ᛒᛦᚦ᛫ᚠᚱᚩᚠᚢᚱ᛫ᚠᛁᚱᚪ᛫ᚷᛖᚻᚹᛦᛚᚳᚢᛗ.","12":"側経意責家方家閉討店暖育田庁載社転線宇"}
```

```
echo json_encode($teste);
// Resultado sem o `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`:
// {"4":"\u16a0\u16c7\u16bb\u16eb\u16d2\u16e6\u16a6\u16eb\u16a0\u16b1\u16a9\u16a0\u16a2\u16b1\u16eb\u16a0\u16c1\u16b1\u16aa\u16eb\u16b7\u16d6\u16bb\u16b9\u16e6\u16da\u16b3\u16a2\u16d7.","12":"\u5074\u7d4c\u610f\u8cac\u5bb6\u65b9\u5bb6\u9589\u8a0e\u5e97\u6696\u80b2\u7530\u5e81\u8f09\u793e\u8ee2\u7dda\u5b87"}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Utilize apenas isto:

```
// Acima disto sem alteração!
$result->close();

foreach($temp as $x){
    $json[ $x['seat_number'] ] = $x['payment_status'];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b222ccf4672dd5215c0c32c25a1aad9a52e7c70a)

Dessa forma o `$json` será uma array correta e entrará corretamente no `json_encode` como um array e não uma string.

Comment: pode dar uma olhada no código abaixo ?

Comment: Eu editei, veja agora.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda ;)